# Javascript Image slideshow doesn't work

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to get one image from this array to display every two seconds using Javascript, but I can't seem to get it to work. The id is correct and the image locations are correct and all spelt right. Not sure what's going wrong, any help would be greatly appreciated! Thanks in advance!

```
var images = new Array();
images[0] = "images/slideshowimage1.jpg";
images[1] = "images/slideshowimage2.jpg";
images[2] = "images/slideshowimage3.jpg";
images[3] = "images/slideshowimage4.jpg";

var counter = 0;
function ChangePic()
{
    counter++;
    document.getElementById('carpic').src = images[counter];

    if(counter == images.length)
    {
    counter = 0;    
    }

setTimeout("ChangePic()",2000)
}
```

Comment: Where do you call `ChangePic()` function?

Comment: I have it inside another function that's making other changes to my website

Comment: Do you get any errors in console?

Comment: create a demo in jsfiddle.net that replicates problem...haven't really identified what it is or isn't doing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, first off you need to wrap the call in the setTimeout in a function, not a string.

Second, the counter never reaches the value 0 because you increase it's value by 1 from the start.  You want to do something like this:

```
var images = new Array();
images[0] = "images/slideshowimage1.jpg";
images[1] = "images/slideshowimage2.jpg";
images[2] = "images/slideshowimage3.jpg";
images[3] = "images/slideshowimage4.jpg";

var counter = 0;
function ChangePic()
{
    document.getElementById('carpic').src = images[counter];

    // a more efficient if/else statement can be written like this:

    // don't forget that the array starts with 0, so you need array length -1
    (counter == images.length-1) ? counter = 0 : counter++;
}

// need to move this out of the ChangePic function
setTimeout(function() {ChangePic()}, 2000);
```

Comment: You don't need to create a new function in the timeout, you can pass `ChangePic` by reference

Answer (score 0):

You should remove the double quotes and braces in the `setTimeout` function.

It should be:

```
setTimeout(ChangePic, 2000);
```

Answer (score 0):

Hm, I think there are a couple of problems here. First is a syntax error, then a logic error.

The syntax error is your argument for `setTimeout`. It should be `setTimeout(ChangePic, 2000)`, rather than `setTimeout("ChangePic()", 2000)`.

The logic error is in the position of your increment, `counter++` - in its present position, the values that will end up being used as an index for the array `images[]` will be 1, 2, and 3. Index 0 (the first item in `images[]`) will never be used, since `counter` always gets incremented before it is used as an index (making it impossible for it to be 0 when it is used). What you'll want to do is move `counter++` *after* you use it as an index for `images[]`.

Adjusting your code as little as possible, here's what it might look like:

```
var images = new Array();
images[0] = "images/slideshowimage1.jpg";
images[1] = "images/slideshowimage2.jpg";
images[2] = "images/slideshowimage3.jpg";
images[3] = "images/slideshowimage4.jpg";
var counter = 0;

function ChangePic() {
    document.getElementById('carpic').src = images[counter];
    counter++;

    if (counter == images.length) {
        counter = 0;
    }

    setTimeout(ChangePic, 2000)
}

// Call function at end to begin slideshow cycle
ChangePic();
```

Here's a [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/PLcHV/1/) to show you what this does. (Open your browser's debug console to view the output.) Hope this is what you were looking for! If not, let me know and I'll be happy to help further.